# How to add apt dependencies to setup.py

Tags: apt, python, dependencies, python3, opengl

I have a module called [ModernGL](https://github.com/cprogrammer1994/ModernGL)

I want to add the following modules as dependencies for my module when installing on Ubuntu. I have some installing notes already:

```
apt-get install python3-dev libgl1-mesa-dev libx11-dev
python3 setup.py install
```

- How can I detect if `python3-dev`, `libgl1-mesa-dev` and `libx11-dev` is not installed?
- Can I add these packages as a dependency in the **setup.py**?
- How can I print a message from **setup.py** properly to let the user know what to install?

Some files that are relevant:

- The [setup.py](https://github.com/cprogrammer1994/ModernGL/blob/master/setup.py)
- The [README](https://github.com/cprogrammer1994/ModernGL#installing-on-ubuntu-from-source) with ubuntu install notes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A while ago I added these lines to a shell script:

```
INSTALL=
for P in gnome-common yelp-tools yelp-xsl; do
    if ! dpkg -l $P >/dev/null 2>&1; then
        INSTALL="$INSTALL $P"
    fi
done
if [ -n "$INSTALL" ]; then
    echo "To use this script, please install required packages by running this command:"
    echo "\nsudo apt install$INSTALL\n"
    exit 1
fi
```

The same approach can be applied with Python code, I suppose.

Comment: @DombiSzabolcs: Great that it proved to be useful. I was too lazy to convert it to Python. ;)